# javascript if then load ajax and input count

Tags: javascript

How can i load ajax in this "if statment":

```
if (code) {
          drawLine(code.location.topLeftCorner, code.location.topRightCorner, "#FF3B58");
          drawLine(code.location.topRightCorner, code.location.bottomRightCorner, "#FF3B58");
          drawLine(code.location.bottomRightCorner, code.location.bottomLeftCorner, "#FF3B58");
          drawLine(code.location.bottomLeftCorner, code.location.topLeftCorner, "#FF3B58");
         
          // Then here i would like to call ajax and visit a url like this

          $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              type: 1,
              name: name,
              email: email                  
             },
             cache: false,
             success: function(dataResult){
             var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
             if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
        
             /// my code if success
            
                                
             }
             else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
        
           ///my code if failure.
        
            }
    
           }
         });
          
          
        } else {
```

And my other quistions is how can i check with javascript if a input has 6 char/numbers entered in it and if then do like the samething executing ajax but in other function and not within the if statement shown

Answer (score 0):

var a = documentGetElementByid("mystringlength").length;

if (a == 6) {

$.ajax({
url: "process_six_figure.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
},
cache: false,
success: function(dataResult){
// process your six figure input here
}),
failure: function(dataResult){
// handle your errors here
{);

});

Answer (score 0):

Always try to make your code organized.

The right way to do HTTP requests is the following:

```
function ajaxHTTP(url, dataPost, passAsParameter){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: dataPost,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){
            passAsParameter(data); //The function as passed as parameter
       },
       error: function(errMsg) {
            //Network error
       }
   });
}

ajaxHTTP("https://example.net/my_server.lang", { field: "value" }, nameOfYourFunction);
function nameOfYourFunction(data){
   //Make what you need (if and else)
}
```